# how to use webview in NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I am trying to use collapsing toolbar and I am trying to implement `NestedScrollView` along with collapsing toolbar and inside the `NestedScrollView` I need to use `WebView`.

But I am not successful. Please explain me How to use `WebView` inside the `NestedScrollView`.

Here's my code:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:dsm="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/home_carousel_imageview_for_touchpoint_image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/global_default_margin_44px"

                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />


                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >


            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/home_carousel_webview_for_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/global_default_margin_v30"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/global_default_margin_v30"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:textColor="#58595B"
                android:textSize="@dimen/global_default_textSize_34px" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```